# Не получается подключиться к mysql в golang

Tags: mysql, golang, google-app-engine

Как правильно задавать настройки подключения к БД? Параметры настроек правильные, подключался через терминал. На странице выводит только: "Error!". Когда указываю неверные данные, "Error connect " это вообще не выводит. Пытаюсь разместить на Google App Engine, используя другой хостинг mysql

```
package hello

import (
  "net/http"
  "github.com/go-martini/martini"
  "fmt"
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 fmt.Fprintln(w, "mainDesc")
}

const (
  DATABASE = "dbname"
  USERNAME = "name"
  PASSWORD = "pass"
  HOST = "93.189.45.34"
)


func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql",USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@tcp("+HOST+")/"+DATABASE)
    var (
        id          int
        description string
    )
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Error connect ")
    }

    err2 := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM main").Scan(&id, &description)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Error!")
    }
  fmt.Fprintln(w, description)
}
func init() {
  m := martini.Classic()
  m.Get("/", handler)
  m.Get("/go", handler2)
  http.Handle("/", m)
}
```

Comment: `fmt.Fprintln(w, err)` - и посмотреть что же там за ошибка

Comment: dial tcp: missing port in address 93.189.45.34

Comment: Ну а где порт то?

Comment: делаю команду: show variables like 'port'; выводит 3306, а когда ввожу там HOST = "93.189.45.34:3306", на странице выводит: dial tcp 93.189.45.34:3306: socket: operation not permitted

Comment: и что делать теперь?

Comment: у меня по localhost с той же БД связывается, если указать этот порт, а в google app engine снова выдает: dial tcp 93.189.45.34:3306: socket: operation not permitted

Comment: @AdikSaidow Ищите документацию по MySQL. Я с ним почти не работал, но PostgreSQL по умолчанию запрещает для дефолтного юзера коннект по TCP, а чтобы разрешить надо редактировать конфиг. Возможно, у вас та же ситуация.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: да нет, я проверял же это, сайт на localhost, БД на сервере. по tcp удалось связаться, а в GAE почему-то не получается

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям к вопрсоу проблема связана не с кодом на golang, а с настройками окружения.

Есть две вероятные причины:

1. Сервер с MySQL не принимает внешние подключения. Это просто проверить запустив где угодно клиент mysql с параметром --host= адрес. И если соединенеия нет, то настраивать firewall на сервере с mysql
2. Сервер Google App Engine блокирует исходящие коннекты на "нестандартные" порты. В данном случае это более вероятная причина. Проверить и настроить правила для firewall сервера приложений можно, например, в Google Cloud console и разрешить исходящие tcp/ip соединения по нужному порту.

Подробнее про firewall можно почитать [в документации Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/understanding-firewalls)